# Area combo of inner triangles formed by orthocenter, circumcenter, and vertices

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles, plane-geometry

Consider triangle $ABC$. Let point $H$ be the orthocentre and point $O$ be the circumcentre.

> Prove that area of one of triangles $AOH$,$BOH$,$COH$ is equal to the sum of areas of other two.

[image]

Comment: what have you tried so far? Do you have at least drawn a diagram and play around a little with it?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint 1**. $\overrightarrow{OH}=\overrightarrow{OA}+\overrightarrow{OB}+\overrightarrow{OC}$.

**Hint 2**. Area of $\triangle AOH=\frac12 |\overrightarrow{OA}\times\overrightarrow{OH}|$.